# Passing concrete type to view with interface as model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, interface

In my .NET 4.6.1 MVC project I have a partial view that has an `Interface` called `IPaginatedList` as the model.

_Pager.cshtml

```
@model Shared.Abstract.IPaginatedList
```

In my main view I am calling the _Pager partial view while passing in an object called `Medals` which is of type `PaginatedList`

Index.cshtml

```
@Html.Partial("_AjaxPager", Model.Medals)
```

Medal Object

```
public PaginatedList<Medal> Medals { get; set; }
```

The `PaginatedList` class is setup as follows

```
public class PaginatedList<T> : List<T>, IPaginatedList
{
}
```

You can see that it inherits from `IPaginatedList` and a generic `List<T>`.

I'm transfering my code to .NET Core 3.1 and I am getting an error when using this exact same code.

> The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type
> 'PaginatedList`1[MedalViewModel]',
> but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type
> 'Shared.Abstract.IPaginatedList'.

What do I have to do to resolve this issue?

Comment: There is something off here, cause you are calling `_AjaxPager` but showing model for `_Pager.cshtml`. Also you state that `Medals` is `PaginatedList<Medal>` but the error says it's `PaginatedList<SeriesViewModel>`. Check that there is no other `IPaginatedList` interface in the solution and correct namespace is used everywhere.

Comment: PaginatedList accepts a generic parameter of T.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But if I understood correctly the code - `PaginatedList<Medal>`  should be passed to the view, but error claims that `PaginatedList<SeriesViewModel>` was.

Comment: The error is occuring on the line @Html.Partial("_AjaxPager", Model.Medals). Model.Medals is of type PaginatedList<T> which inherits from IPaginatedList<T>. It works fine in .NET but ASP Core throws an error

Comment: _"`Model.Medals` is of type `PaginatedList<T>`"_ - that is not true based on this `public PaginatedList<Medal> Medals { get; set; }` line in the provided code. Please fix the question with correct code and ideally [mre].

Comment: PaginatedList<Medal> is the same as PaginatedList<T> as Medal is the generic type T in this scenario

Comment: @GuruStron Im sorry, after some review I noticed the PaginatedList inherited from IPaginatedList in the same folder path, but the partial view models where referencing a IPaginatedList in a sub folder called "Abstract" of that path. I must have copied the file over twice when transfering the project files.

Comment: Yep, as I suggested in the first comment - _"Check that there is no other `IPaginatedList` interface in the solution and correct namespace is used everywhere. "_

Comment: @GuruStron do you want to add an answer and I will mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work correctly because `PaginatedList<T>` is a `IPaginatedList`. Check that you don't have duplicate `IPaginatedList` interfaces and if you do - either delete extra ones or make sure that correct namespace is used in both places (model and view).